# How to match make link when use queryParams in angular4

Tags: angular

There is a link in my code:

```
<a class="menu-btn" [routerLink]="['/backend/feedback']"   
      [queryParams]="{ id: currentBu?.id || 0}" routerLinkActive="active">反馈查询</a>
```

I want the link be active when the url is
`backend/feedback?id=10`
but is doesn't work. Is it matched exactly when I use queryParams? How can that be fuzzy matched with params?